# What causes this pattern?

Tags: filters, digital, zoom, optics, polarizer

What causes the pattern seen on the image (it is a still from a video)? This doesn't seem to be a Moiré. It seems to be largely related to the camera or the filter (the pattern is fixed and aligned with the camera).  The image was taken through an optical bandpass filter.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some information about the image? I have no idea what it shows, at what scale etc.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about photography and I don't have much information about the image either. I know it is digital, uses an Nm filter and shows shows 2 regular white clouds in a blue sky.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nm filter?  Do you mean a [some number of] nanometer bandpass filter?  If so, that's probably what is causing the pattern.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal-mesh_optical_filter

Comment: Yes, I did mean a nanometer bandpass filter. I didn't have much information to go on, but your answer was still helpful! Thank you.